# Cypress concatenate to find second element

Tags: javascript, css, concatenation, cypress

can someone, please, help, in following case:

Found element with following css selector (there is a list of charts, where only one chart has mark with "Current Day" text on top of it).

```
'div[id*="view-panel"] div.bar_chart g.bar_chart__now > text'
```

Based on that element, want to find another element (which is on found chart - its bottom), which displays name of the day (i.e "Friday"). Tried with following code:

```
cy.get('div[id*="view-panel"] div.bar_chart g.bar_chart__now > text').as('currentDay');
cy.get('@ccurrentDay').find('..').find('..').find('g.bar_chart__xaxis text');
```

Whole css selector for second element (for second code line above), looks:

```
'div[id*="view-panel"] div.bar_chart g.bar_chart__xaxis text'
```

What I tried to achieve is after first found element, go two steps back and find day name of chart bottom, but what I only get is an error:

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: ‘…’, but never found it.
```

What I am doing incorrect in above attempt to concatenate finding element? Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't use aliases in the same method, see: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Aliases

Comment: @Jonah I already used alias but for element which is next sibling to founded one, so you are wrong, it can be used and it works. Issue, here is when you want to back several steps, which I can not figure out, how to write that 'find' command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Within command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within.html#Syntax)

```
cy.get('div[id*="view-panel"] div.bar_chart g.bar_chart__now > text')
.within(()=>{
    cy.get('g.bar_chart__xaxis text')
})
```